# asp.net web application performance issue at initial load

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, precompiled

i have one web application. index.aspx is my default page. 
so my problem is when my app starts for the first time it take 15sec to load the page. in my index.aspx has just simple static menu. when i put a break point in page_load it got hit after 15 sec. so its not my page but something else is causing this issue. may be pre compilation or loading dlls or something.

i really need help on this. i dont know where to look.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you rebuild your application the server has to recompile the code, but should be quicker after the first visit.

Additionally, using the debugger will degrade performance.

If you want to view the site locally with better performance overall you might want to setup a website in IIS, rather than using Visual Studio's built in web server.

Comment: thanks Nick. i have tested this on our staging area. even after multiple request page take min 10sec. am i missing something?

Comment: Are you using the built in web server (Cassini)? It's not built for speed, it's meant to be used for debugging. I imagine you lose performance for the ability to gain in useful debugging information.

Comment: i was using dev web server. but i have tested on our staging IIS. and my app is precompiled. i have another app from the same source which is running fine no problem at all. so is it IIS doing something weird.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly normal.  When you first initialize an application after a fresh deploy, the ASP.NET pages will compile into assemblies for reference in IIS.  There are ways however to precompile these pages.

See the following MSDN article for information on how to precompile your web pages for faster initial load times.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx

Comment: This precompilation was what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Let your page render then click view source and look at the external libraries that a referenced by the page. Normally forcing the client to download a large external javascript library is the cause of this (this library should be cached on the client and not affect future page loads).